# Android: HTTP POST '307'

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, http-post

I am trying to post the byte array of an image to this webservice. I get 307 response code.

```
            URL url = new URL("http://123.456.789:2020/UploadService/AddReportContent");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");


            connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(b.length);

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(b);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            status = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The status response 307 means:

> 307 Temporary Redirect (since HTTP/1.1)
>   In this case, the request should be repeated with another URI; however, future requests should still use the original URI. In contrast to how 302 was historically implemented, the request method is not allowed to be changed when reissuing the original request. For instance, a POST request repeated using another POST request.

So you just need to open the second url, but the upload itself should be done.